# Hibernate ignores @NamedEntityGraph

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We would like to create a relationship between a member (of our fictitious club) and the payments that he has made. 
Thus we created an **entity "member"** and an **entity "premiums"**.

The **member should now all the payments** that he has made in the past. If he hasn't made a payment, the list should be empty. We want to **load** the **member** **lazy** to reduce the amount of database operations.

The **member** look like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.Member.payments",
                 attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("payments"))
public class Member implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 6925248180274039273L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long memberID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "member", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Premium> payments;
```

And the **premium** entity like this:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
public class Premium implements Serializable{

private String year;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long paymentID;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="memberID")
private Member member;
```

We have a query in which we would like to get a member with a specific id. The query looks like this:

```
     public List<Member> findAll(long id) {
     EntityGraph  postGraph=entityManager.getEntityGraph("graph.Member.payments");
        return entityManager
                .createQuery("select m from Member m where m.memberID = (:id)")
                .setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", postGraph)
                .setParameter("id", id)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

If we execute that method, **hibernate doesn't** seem to **load the hint** that we've set. 
In our **server** log we can see that it **creates** the **following query:**

```
Hibernate: 
select
    member0_.memberID as memberID1_0_0_,
    member0_.accountRelationship as accountR2_0_0_,
    member0_.address as address3_0_0_,
    member0_.birthday as birthday4_0_0_,
    member0_.dateOfSeperation as dateOfSe5_0_0_,
    member0_.entryDate as entryDat6_0_0_,
    member0_.family as family7_0_0_,
    member0_.firstName as firstNam8_0_0_,
    member0_.memberShip as memberSh9_0_0_,
    member0_.name as name10_0_0_,
    member0_.terminationDate as termina11_0_0_ 
from
    Member member0_ 
where
    member0_.memberID=?
07-Nov-2017 13:11:47.227 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.nordakademie.iaa.roommgmt.model.Member.payments, could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: de.nordakademie.iaa.roommgmt.model.Member.payments, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: de.nordakademie.iaa.roommgmt.model.Member["payments"])
```

For our project we use a **tomcat 8.5.5, hibernate 5.2.10, spring 4.3.11, H2 1.4.196 and AngularJS 1.6**.

If anything is unclear, please feel free to ask us.

Answer (score 0):

You may check

```
.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", postGraph)
```

instead of 'loadgraph'. Hibernate's behavior is sometimes unpredicatable.